# Use openssl s_server as a reverse proxy

Tags: linux, ssl, reverse-proxy, openssl, port-forwarding

Is it somehow possible to use `openssl s_server` as a kind of reverse proxy by forwarding all data after the handshake to a different port.

To be more concrete, I would like to create a simple *tftp-over-dtls* setting for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not.

Because openssl s_server only does TCP, as mentioned in the output of `man s_server`:

```
DESCRIPTION
       The s_server command implements a generic SSL/TLS server which listens for connections on a given port using SSL/TLS.

OPTIONS
       -accept port
           the TCP port to listen on for connections. If not specified 4433 is used.
```

TFTP uses UDP (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_File_Transfer_Protocol, http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1350.html), so I can't see how you would make this work.

nginx might be able to do what you are looking for, however.

According to /etc/services, an IANA assignment exists for TFTPS, but I can find no RFCs or other documentation about it.

**Edit**

As pointed out in comments - s_server does (in some openSSL releases, e.g. 1.1.0) support DTLS: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/s_server.html.

This is not the case for all openSSL releases though - 1.0.2 (https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/s_server.html) and 1.0.1 (https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.1/apps/s_server.html) do not support DTLS.

Comment: s_server can also serve as a DTLS server, which is using UDP. So if the forwarding is somehow possible, I could try that. (I edited my question)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using sufficiently recent OpenSSL and Bash, you can redirect input and output of the "s_server" command to a socket. On the (proxy) server you could run:

```
exec 3<> /dev/udp/mytftpserver.com/69; openssl s_server -dtls -port 1069 \
  -key x.key -cert x.cert -quiet <&3 >&3
```

On the client side start communicating to the proxy server, port 1069, with your DTLS capable TFTP client:

```
openssl s_client -dtls -connect myproxyserver.com:1069
```

However for TFTP an actual file transfer would originate from a port other than 69, for that the then established DTLS association would not be usable most likely.